# How to get ImageView resource in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview

The app has 3 Imageviews and 1 Button in the same activity, by clicking the button, 3 images will be randomly generated from a pool of images (say 100 images in total) and displayed on the Imageviews.

the user clicks one of the Imageviews and a new dialog pops up and showing the clicked image again with some texts.

Problem: I know I can store the result/tag when the imageviews have been setup, but I need to run an if loop in order to set the image in dialog. So is there any way I can get the clicked image resource then I can use it directly in the dialog? In other word, I want to do like this:

`img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.(img2.getDrawableID()))`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView2.setImageDrawable(imageView1.getDrawable());
```